# How can I get cargo to recompile changed files automatically?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have heard cargo has the ability to automatically recompile changed source files, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to tell it to do so.

For now, I am manually running `cargo build` or `cargo run` every time I want to type check my code. I would prefer to instead simply save the file and see the results in the neighboring terminal window.

In case you still have no idea what I'm talking about, I'm looking for the cargo equivalent of `sbt ~compile` or `sbt ~run`.

It seems strangely hard to find, so I'm starting to wonder if it's really supported. It's possible someone had said cargo could detect changed files and recompile them when what he meant to say was that cargo could detect *unchanged* files and *avoid* recompiling them, like `make`.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

#### cargo watch

In case you are working on a server project (e.g. hyper, iron, etc) that keeps running and you need it to be restarted when files change, you can use [`cargo watch`](https://github.com/watchexec/cargo-watch). Install:

```
cargo install cargo-watch
```

And then run:

```
cargo watch -x run
```

And to watch changes in only the `src` folder and clear the console use:

```
cargo watch -c -w src -x run
```

See the [cargo-watch README](https://github.com/watchexec/cargo-watch#readme) for more examples.

#### watchexec

Alternatively, you can use [watchexec](https://github.com/watchexec/watchexec). Install it:

```
cargo install watchexec-cli
```

And then use it like this:

```
watchexec -r cargo run
```

Comment: Thank you for watchexec! cargo-watch only works for cargo.

Comment: This only seem to work for a binary, when I tried with a library I got an error of `error: a bin target must be available for `cargo run``.

Comment: `watchexec`  now has a separate CLI package so the actual install command is `cargo install watchexec-cli`. Also the proper invocation for the current version does not have quotes, so it's `watchexec --restart cargo run`.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be any support built in, but there is an extension ([`cargo-watch`](https://github.com/passcod/cargo-watch)) to detect changes using `inotify`.

When I found it, it wouldn't work with stable (or current) Rust, but I've since patched it.
It could still use some work, but it certainly speeds up the compile/fix-errors cycle.

Answer (score 4):

I use nodemon with this command:

```
nodemon --watch src -e rs --exec cargo check
```

All this does is watch all the rs files in the src folder and run cargo check.

Comment: `npm i -g nodemon`
You'll need to install nodemon globally using npm before running the above

Comment: You can use ```npx nodemon --watch src -e rs --exec cargo check```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the distinction is that running `cargo run` twice won't build the code twice, unless the input files have changed. As far as I know, Cargo doesn't have the functionality you want built-in. You could file a feature request. In the meantime, I'd suggest you just use [`watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch). You could also use something like [`guard`](https://github.com/guard/guard). Using `watch` is simpler, but would just run your code every N seconds. `guard` would require more setup, but would be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

#### Another option is using `entr`

```
ls -r | entr cargo run
```

This will recursively list all files in the current directory. Then redirect them to the `entr` command which watches for changes to those files and then finally runs `cargo run`

Comment: `brew install entr` first

Comment: I like the idea but it's `ls -R` not `ls -r`. Sadly it's not working on my system. 
This is working example:
$ find . -type f  | entr echo 123
This is not:
$ find . -type f  | entr cargo run
Probably it's because `cargo run` command isn't exits immideately.

Comment: Finally I found out how to make it work:

`find src | entr -r cargo run`

Comment: With all this said, the best option usually still is to use `cargo`

Answer (score 0):

The most stable option for me was to use npx with nodemon

```
npx nodemon --watch src -e rs --exec cargo run
```

You'll need nodejs and npm installed.

Answer (score -6):

In you Visual Studio Code : Go to <kbd>File</kbd> and check <kbd>Auto Save</kbd> which will automatically save the changes made.

Comment: This does not accomplish the goal of **automatically**.

Comment: No, it does not. Saving the file does not cause Cargo to build it, which is the point of this question.

Comment: This won my prize for most off topic answer in last couple years.